# Why limit the total amount of shared memory available?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

I have some large memory processes that share memory on a CentOS 7 system. I am tuning the memory system for them. For kernel.shmmax and kernel.shmall the RedHat documentation states:

> kernel.shmmax defines the maximum size in bytes of a single shared memory
> segment that a Linux process can allocate in its virtual address
> space.
>
> kernel.shmall sets the total amount of shared memory pages that can be used
> system wide.

Why are there such limits on shared memory? I can limit the total memory a user or process uses with limits or cgroups. Why would I want to limit the total shared memory available on the system? Does the system take a performance hit when it has a lot of shared memory to manage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of system hygiene and a bit of legacy. The cgroup controls are relatively new to Linux (2.6.24 and later), where shmmax/shmall were present in the kernel as early as the 1.2.x series:

`ipc/shm.c`

```
    {
            struct shminfo shminfo;
            if (!buf)
                    return -EFAULT;
            shminfo.shmmni = SHMMNI;
            shminfo.shmmax = SHMMAX;
            shminfo.shmmin = SHMMIN;
            shminfo.shmall = SHMALL;
            shminfo.shmseg = SHMSEG;
            err = verify_area (VERIFY_WRITE, buf, sizeof (struct shminfo));
            if (err)
                    return err;
            memcpy_tofs (buf, &shminfo, sizeof(struct shminfo));
            return max_shmid;
    }
```

The limiting philosophy of linux has evolved over the last 21 years. Back then, the design-pattern of global limits was dominant. You didn't want to use all of your RAM for IPC, so you needed to set a high-water-mark for it to ensure there was enough space for everything else. This can work with modern cgroups as well; individual limits for your processes, with a global limit to ensure swap is avoided and the whole system still works well.

Comment: Looking farther back... looks like shmmax was present in the 1.0 version! This is some original stuff, here.